# Finding the first element less than a certain value in an unsorted vector (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, vector

Pretty simple, and I thought I knew what I was doing, but apparently not.  Anyways.

I need to find the first element in a vector that is less than a specific value.  Here is the code that I have been using:

```
t = 0:0.01:5;

u = ((2)*exp(-10.*t).*cos((4.*sqrt(6)).*t) + ((5)./sqrt(6)).*exp(-10.*t).*sin((4.*sqrt(6)).*t));

for a = 1:size(u)
if u(a) < (0.05)
    disp(a)
    break
end
end
```

The value that I'm trying to find is the first element less than 0.05, however, when I run my code, I don't get anything.

What could I be doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

@user2994291 has correctly pointed out where your loop based solution is going wrong (+1).

However I would also add that what you are trying to do can simply be accomplished by:

```
find(u < 0.05, 1, 'first')
```

Technically, the third input is not necessary - you could just use:

```
find(u < 0.05, 1)
```

However, I seem to recall reading at some point that `find` will work faster if you provide the third input.

Answer (score 3):

The upper bound of your for loop is probably equal to 1.

In your case, u is a row vector (can't say 100% for sure in `MATLAB` as I only have access to `GNU Octave` right now), but calling size(u) will probably give back [1 501] as an answer. Your for-loop will select 1 as upper bound.

Try replacing size(u) with `size(u,2)` or, even better, with `length(u)`. I get a = 24 as an answer.

Edit:

from your questions I assume you are a MATLAB beginner, therefore I strongly advise you to look into the built-in `debugger` (you can add breakpoints by clicking on the left vertical bar next to the desired line of code), this would have helped you identify the error with ease and will save you a lot of time in the future.

Comment: +1 for correctly diagnosing the problem with the loop-based solution provided by the OP. However, see my answer for a much more efficient method for solving the problem.

Comment: You might want `numel(u)` instead of `size(u,2)` or `length(u)`. It's the general form for looping through all elements of an array, regardless of shape. The `length(u)` and `size(u,2)` will only work with vectors and row vectors, respectively. Especially in code that takes arrays from outside callers, `length()` can cause latent indexing bugs.